# AngularJS animation addClass for transitions

Tags: angularjs

I have an AngularJS directive where I want to click something, an element gets created, and uses CSS animations to transitions from one size/position to another.

Non-functional demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/ChrisMBarr/xv23s73f/4/

Right now I am doing the following, which I found in [the ngAnimate documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate/#applying-directive-specific-styles-to-an-animation)

```
$animate.addClass($box, "transitioning",{
   from:{
      width: $element.width(),
      height: $element.height(),
      top: $element.offset().top,
      left: $element.offset().left
   }
});
```

and this is what my CSS looks like:

```
.fancy-box{
    background: red;
    position: absolute;

}

.transitioning{
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
       -o-transition: all 0.3s;
          transition: all 0.3s;   

      top: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
}
```

Basically, my `transitioning` class is not being applied, and the styles are not being set, so nothing is animating.  What am I missing here?

Comment: you are writing `transitioning` in a wrong place

Comment: @JhonSmith ok, so where should it be instead?  According to [the documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate/#applying-directive-specific-styles-to-an-animation) it should be the 2nd parameter.  Is this wrong?

Comment: @JhonSmith Any further input on this?  I am still stuck with this and your previous comment was not helpful.  You seem to know how this works, and I'd love to know as well.

Answer (score 2):

The main problem is that you are calling `$animate.addClass` from inside the click handler.  If you do this, then you need to follow it up with a `$scope.$apply`.  Otherwise, angular doesn't know that it needs to do anything.

```
testApp.directive("makeBigger", ["$animate", function ($animate) {
     return {
        restrict: "A",
        scope: true,
        link: function ($scope, $element){
            $element.on("click", function (ev) {
                var $box = $("<div class='fancy-box'></div>").insertAfter($element);

                $animate.addClass($box, "transitioning",{
                    from:{
                        width: $element.width(),
                        height: $element.height(),
                        top: $element.offset().top,
                        left: $element.offset().left
                    }
                });
                $scope.$apply()
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

Also, you should use `transitioning-add` in your css.  From the docs: 
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate/service/$animate

angular first adds the class: `foo-add` and then `foo` and `foo-add-active`.  I think the idea is to put the transition stuff into the `foo-add` class.

*EDITED to take out bad advice about `animate.enter`*  It turns out angular enter is crazier than I remembered.

Comment: Doh, `$scope.apply()`! how could I forget!  However, doing the `$animate.enter` will not animate the element.  Updated demo link here: http://jsfiddle.net/xv23s73f/7/

Comment: Basically, I just want to animate an element from one size/position to another size/position and then run a callback function when completed.  I'd prefer to use the built-in angular/CSS animations, but I'm finding it _really_ difficult to work with.  I might just stick with a jQuery animation.